# Definite integration of Weierstrass sigma and Jacobi theta function

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, elliptic-functions

Scrolling through QFT articles I found, not solved, the following definite integrals:
$$\int_{I} d^{2}z \ln \left| \sigma(z) \right|,$$
$$\int_{I'} d^{2}z \ln \left| \theta_{1}(z) \right|,$$
$$\int_{I'} d^{2}z \ln \left| \theta_{2}(z) \right|.$$
Here $z = \alpha_{1} + i\alpha_{2}$ and $\sigma(z)$ is the [Weierstrass sigma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassSigmaFunction.html) with half-periods $\omega_{1} = R$ and $\omega_{2} = T$ and modular parameter $\tau = i\frac{T}{R}$, while $\theta_{1}(z)$ and $\theta_{2}(z)$ are the first two [Jacobi theta functions](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) with modular parameter $\tau = i\frac{T}{2R}$. The domains of integration are $I = [0,r][0,t]$ and $I' = [-\frac{r}{2}, \frac{r}{2}][-\frac{t}{2},\frac{t}{2}]$, with $t < T$ and $r < R$.
Being a simple physicist I managed to grasp their meaning in the context, but I have no clue on how to perform analytically the integration, or whether a closed form is achievable at all. Can someone help me through their computation?

Comment: $\sigma$ has an infinite product definition so your integral reduces to a series of terms like $\int_I \ln|z- a\omega_1+b\omega_2|  d^2z$. For $\theta$ it is the same except the infinite product is non-trivial.

Comment: Great tips, thanks! I think I figured out how to work with the $\sigma$. In what sense though there is an infinite product also in the $\theta$? Aren't they infinite sums?

Comment: The Weierstrass Zeta function is the logarithmic derivative of the Weierstrass Sigma function and the Weierstrass Zeta function has a nice Laurent series expansion that you should be able to integrate term wise and use complex integration and the residue theorem to calculate finite sums involving omega, tau or T and R. If t and r less than T and R it might just be a very simple term.